# How remove rows or filter rows with some identical columns values by some criteria?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rdbms

I have a table which I filter and sort with this query

```
 select * from XXXX where Segment='Gewerbe' and Division='Strom' and consumption >= 1000 and consumption < 2000 and rank<= 5 and market_id='39a2e05fd43300c998558ef56bca18e2' order by consumption ,rank
```

The result set contains basically three groups of results which are grouped `MARKET_ID` and `RANK`. Each subresult differs by `RANK` (1..N).

The difficult part: I am interested only in the subresults with the highest `RANK` In this case I need each row with `RANK=5`. So I want to eliminate the rows with `RANK=1..4`. Note that highest `RANK` for each subresult might be smaller than 5.

[Result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvuW0.png)

Comment: Your query hard codes a fixed value for `MARKET_ID`.  Is this really the query you intend to run?

Comment: For demonstration purposes yes. MARKET_ID + CONSUMPTION  would form a group with RANK as variable value. We need to have the MARKET_ID + CONSUMPTION + COSTS_NETTO as a result where the maximum RANK is 5 as in this case (for a given CONSUMPTION range (1000-2000 here)

Comment: So why not just change `and rank <= 5` to `and rank = 5`?

Comment: "Note that highest RANK for each subresult might be smaller than 5." The max RANK might be  any value smaller than the filter used in the where clause. The data set is as it is.

Comment: Then I suggest to use [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) with a [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html) ordered by descending rank, 1 will be highest then

Answer (score 0):

I think the following would work too:

```
select market_id, consumption, max(costs_netto), max(rank) from XXX where Segment='Gewerbe' and Division='Strom' and consumption >= 1000 and consumption < 2000 and rank<= 5 and market_id='39a2e05fd43300c998558ef56bca18e2'[enter image description here][1]  group by market_id, consumption  order by market_id, consumption
```

[Result with grouping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUwfa.png)